# What kind of Index should I use?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

We store records with the following structure:
Ssn, lname, fname
in a data file ordered on lname

If we want an index on lname because lots of queries search based on
last name, what kind of index is needed?

Comment: Can you add more details and be more specific in your question?

Comment: Hi, Suppose We store records with the following structure:Ssn, lname, fname
in a data file ordered on lname, What kind of index is needed?

Answer (score 1):

From what i can get from your requirements, Try adding **B-tree index** to that particular column .

Comment: Lets consider Clustering index, Non clustering index, Primary index, Secondary index are the options. What do you think?

Comment: Clustered index  or Primary index can only be applied on primary key , since lastname can not be a primary key as multiple can have same lastname so you can leverage clustered indexes. Now the only option you have is secondary index or non clustered index. There are 2 types of non clustered indexes available, HASH Based and B-tree . Yes there are others but these 2 are the main . Although hash based has a better performance result but i does not work well with LIKE or some regular expression . B tree seems to be a great option.

Comment: Wait, aren't secondary indexes different from clustered indexes?

Comment: yes they do ??  Your point ?

Comment: You said you can leverage clustered indexes and then you said the only option you have is secondary index or non clustered index, I don't understand, can you please be specific which index am I supposed to use?

Comment: I think you have some mis confusion , 

primary index = clustered index,

secondary index = non clustered index

Comment: But then again you said you can leverage clustered indexes and then in the next line you said only option is non clustered index. So can you clear this up? What index should I use ?

Comment: Sorry my bad , it should be 'can't'

Answer (score 0):

For people names, I recommend the composite `INDEX(lname, fname)`.  This will help (to some extent) each of these:

```
WHERE lname = 'James'
WHERE lname = 'James' AND fname LIKE 'R%'
WHERE lname = 'James' AND fname = 'Rick'
```

Your clustered `PRIMARY KEY` is probably SSN; this index may as well be a secondary (non-clustered) index.

In MySQL, BTree is essentially the only choice.  Anyway, BTree is at least nearly as good as Hash.

Caution!  Storing SSNs is a serious security problem.  If you lose your machine, or it is hacked into, you will be in deed dodo.  Meanwhile, don't plan on me giving you my SSN.